# Проблемы с разметкой фрагмента

Tags: java, android, xml

Есть фрагмент:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCamera"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/colorTop"
    android:text="@string/btn_make_photo"
    android:textColor="@color/colorText"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnGallery"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/colorBottom"
    android:text="@string/btn_load_from_gallery"
    android:textColor="@color/colorText"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

который размещен в данном LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/llMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="ru.snoitacilppa.mosaicpicture.MainActivity">    
</LinearLayout>
```

В режиме дизайна я вижу это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако при запуске получается следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему при запуске кнопки не занимают половину экрана?

Comment: Попробуйте им высоту 0dp поставить

Comment: @ЮрийСПб если вы имеете ввиду поменять высоту у кнопок, то это не спасает

Comment: попробуйте очистить кэш. File->invalidate caches и рестарт

Comment: @Turalllb также не помогло

Comment: Может вы несколько xml создали, а подключили к активити не тот? Сама разметка, выложенная вами, правильная. Проблема в чем то другом

Comment: @Turalllb я пробовал создавать новый проект и переносить в него все из старого, но проблема осталась. xml подключен верно

Comment: Я запускаю ваш xml и у меня всё как надо: две большие кнопки,которые делят экран поровну между собой. Не ищи проблему в верстке. Попробую обновить AVD ,  хотя это вряд ли. Возможно какая то глупая ошибка, которую вы не замечаете. Создайте новый проект, не надо переносить из старого. Создайте пустой класс, который будет показывать этот xml. Еще уберите фон кнопок, уберите текст. Локализуйте проблему. Пробуйте запускать на другом эмуляторе. На имеющем эмуляторе сделайте Wide ..что то там.. это очистить память эмулятора.

Comment: @Turalllb проблема решилась, когда я еще раз создал новый проект и аккуратно перенес туда старый. так и не понял, в чем была ошибка, но не в эмуляторе, т.к. на моем телефоне было то же самое